# Достать название функции из словаря и вызвать ее

Tags: python, методы, словарь

Есть словарь, в котором есть название функции btnnewgame

```
methods = {
        'btn_newGame': 'btnewgame',
    }
```

Есть функция

```
    def btnewgame(self):

        self.bank.setText('100000')
        self.pr_price_1.setText(str(random.randrange(500,1000)))
        self.pr_price_2.setText(str(random.randrange(500, 1000)))
        self.pr_price_3.setText(str(random.randrange(500, 1000)))
        self.pr_price_4.setText(str(random.randrange(500, 1000)))
```

Как мне вызвать эту функцию, взяв значение из словаря по ключу?
Пробовал `method["stop-service"]()` не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать надо кавычки в словаре.

```
def btnewgame():
    print("privet")


methods = {
    'btn_newGame': btnewgame
}

methods['btn_newGame']()
```

Comment: Не работало потому что btnewgame() находился ниже словаря. Переместил все и заработало. Спасибо

Comment: @maksik172
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

поскольку вы храните в словаре имя, а не ссылку на функцию, можно сделать как-то так

```
def btnewgame():
    print('btnewgame')

methods = {
    'btn_newGame': 'btnewgame',
}

locals()[methods['btn_newGame']]()    # btnewgame
```

а если нужно вызвать метод класса, то чуть посложнее

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def btnewgame(self):
        print(self.i, 'btnewgame')

methods = {
    'btn_newGame': 'btnewgame',
}

b = A(1)
getattr(b, methods['btn_newGame'])()   # 1 btnewgame
```